# SQL Server Update XML node from XML document in XML Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-update, xquery

I need some help: I'm trying to update an XML node from an XML document stored in an XML column from my database.

This is the structure of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STA11]
(   
    [ID_STA11] [dbo].[int] NOT NULL,    
    [COD_ARTICU] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,        
    [CAMPOS_ADICIONALES] [xml](CONTENT [dbo].[CAMPOS_ADICIONALES_STA11]) NULL
    
 CONSTRAINT [PK_STA11] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_STA11] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The field `CAMPOS_ADICIONALES` has an XML SCHEMA stored in the database, this XML schema has the following structure:

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [dbo].[CAMPOS_ADICIONALES_STA11] AS 
N'<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="CAMPOS_ADICIONALES">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                    <xsd:all>
                        <xsd:element name="CA_TAG" type="CA_TAG_schemeType" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:simpleType name="CA_TAG_schemeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>'
GO
```

The field `CAMPOS_ADICIONALES` has the following XML data stored:

```
<CAMPOS_ADICIONALES>
  <CA_TAG></CA_TAG>
</CAMPOS_ADICIONALES>
```

I need to update the value of the `<CA_TAG>` element in the XML document, but all of the approaches I was trying gave me an error. So far I tried:

```
UPDATE STA11
SET CAMPOS_ADICIONALES.modify('
  replace value of (/CAMPOS_ADICIONALES/CA_TAG/text())[1]
  with sql:variable("@ValorCampoAdicional")
')
WHERE COD_ARTICU = '0100100129';
```

resulting in:

> Error: Msg 9312, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> XQuery [STA11.CAMPOS_ADICIONALES.modify()]: 'text()' is not supported on simple typed or 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyType' elements, found 'element(CA_TAG,CA_TAG_schemeType) *'.

Another approach:

```
UPDATE [STA11]
SET CAMPOS_ADICIONALES.modify('
    replace value of (/CAMPOS_ADICIONALES/CA_TAG)[1]/text()[1]
    with "basura"
')
WHERE [COD_ARTICU] = '0100100129'
```

and its result:

> Error: Msg 9312, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
> XQuery [STA11.CAMPOS_ADICIONALES.modify()]: 'text()' is not supported on simple typed or 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyType' elements, found 'element(CA_TAG,CA_TAG_schemeType) ?'.

And other similar attempts, but with the same result or a similar error, it seems to be a problem with the datatype of the element, but I can't find any way to cast a value within the XQuery syntax.

Is it possible to do this without the use of the REPLACE function in combination with other STRING functions of TSQL?
Is there a "native" XML method?

What do you think?

**UPDATE: @YitzhakKhabinsky has pointed me in the right direction, the way to do this is using the following TSQL Code:**

```
DECLARE @ValorCampoAdicional VARCHAR(100) = 'Hello there';
UPDATE dbo.STA11
    SET CAMPOS_ADICIONALES.modify('
      replace value of (/CAMPOS_ADICIONALES/CA_TAG)[1]
      with sql:variable("@ValorCampoAdicional") cast as CA_TAG_schemeType?
    ')
    WHERE COD_ARTICU = '0100100129';
```

But here is a new problem...with this code we can update an XML field with the characteristics that I mentioned before, and we can use an  SQL Variable to dynamically update the value, so the new problem is:

As you can see, the xml node that I'm trying to update is

```
/CAMPOS_ADICIONALES/CA_TAG
```

Is there a way to construct dynamically this XPath inside the statement or inside a function? If I try to do this:

```
DECLARE @ValorCampoAdicional VARCHAR(100) = 'Hello there';
DECLARE @CampoAdicional VARCHAR(100) = 'CA_TAG';

UPDATE dbo.STA11
SET CAMPOS_ADICIONALES.modify('
  replace value of (/CAMPOS_ADICIONALES/' + @CampoAdicional + ')[1]
  with sql:variable("@ValorCampoAdicional") cast as CA_TAG_schemeType?
')
WHERE COD_ARTICU = '0100100129';
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 8172, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The argument 1 of the XML data type method "modify" must be a string literal.

Completion time: 2023-06-29T15:26:09.7878630-03:00
```

Or if I try to do this:

```
DECLARE @ValorCampoAdicional VARCHAR(100) = 'Hello there';
DECLARE @CampoAdicional VARCHAR(100) = 'CA_TAG';

UPDATE dbo.STA11
SET CAMPOS_ADICIONALES.modify('
  replace value of (/CAMPOS_ADICIONALES/sql:variable("@CampoAdicional"))[1]
  with sql:variable("@ValorCampoAdicional") cast as CA_TAG_schemeType?
')
WHERE COD_ARTICU = '0100100129';
```

I get the this error:

```
Msg 9335, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
XQuery [dbo.STA11.CAMPOS_ADICIONALES.modify()]: The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported.

Completion time: 2023-06-29T15:27:23.5358094-03:00
```

So, this is the situation @YitzhakKhabinsky, I've tried to put this in a comment but was impossible, and a new Question will not contribute to enriching the community.

**UPDATE 2 - Finally the solution**

For those who have a similar situation, here's is the code that solves my problem. Its an UDF in SQL Server which return an XML object and use that result in an UPDATE statement for an XML field:

Thanks again to @YitzhakKhabinsky  who pointed me in the right direction:

```
 IF (OBJECT_ID('fn_SetearCampoAdicional','FN') IS NOT NULL) DROP FUNCTION fn_SetearCampoAdicional
GO
CREATE FUNCTION fn_SetearCampoAdicional(
    @dataXML XML,
    @CampoAdicional VARCHAR(999),
    @ValorCampoAdicional VARCHAR(999)
)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN    

    DECLARE @tagApertura varchar(999)
    DECLARE @tagCierre varchar(999)
    DECLARE @xmlInsert AS XML 
    DECLARE @resultado AS XML

    set @tagApertura = '<' + @CAMPOADICIONAL+ '>'
    set @tagCierre = '</' + @CAMPOADICIONAL+ '>'

    set @xmlInsert = @tagApertura + @ValorCampoAdicional + @tagCierre

    set @resultado = (select CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@dataXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                               ,CAST(@dataXML.query('/CAMPOS_ADICIONALES/*[local-name(.) eq sql:variable("@CampoAdicional")][1]') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                               ,CAST(@xmlInsert AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))AS XML))

    RETURN @resultado
END;
GO
```

Comment: I think your problem is that the XML data type only stores a parsed representation of the data given to it, not the exact bytes verbatim, so your inserted XML has been optimized to `<CAMPOS_ADICIONALES><CA_TAG /></CAMPOS_ADICIONALES>`. This means that there is no `text()` value to replace because it's null. Have you considered deleting the `<CA_TAG />` and inserting a new one in its place?

Comment: you cannot replace something that isn't there  see: https://dbfiddle.uk/C8W1LJ0t  and https://dbfiddle.uk/dVlq3583

Comment: nah, the problem is that it's a schema:ed xml, one cannot use text for those. There's some info here: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/fun-with-static-xquery-evaluation-1/

Comment: Thanks @siggemannen It seems that the problem that I am facing its related with the  link that you've posted, but because I am so new in this I can't move forward, could you give an example that helps me to solve the problem?

Comment: To be honest, i'm not an expert on these XML schemas. What you can do is copy the data into another table without the schema xml specifier, update it, and then update back the original. Probably there's a better way though

Comment: I think because the type is *defined* as `xs:string` then `text()` doesn't make sense. Instead just do `replace value of (/CAMPOS_ADICIONALES/CA_TAG)[1] with sql:variable("@ValorCampoAdicional")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It shows how to update a typed XML column.

Note the use of `cast as ...` when replacing the `<CA_TAG>` element value. It is required when the value must be of a specific **user defined** type as defined by the XML Schema.

If an element is one of W3C “http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema” data types, its value can be specified directly without casting.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.CAMPOS_ADICIONALES_STA11 AS 
N'<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="CAMPOS_ADICIONALES">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                    <xsd:all>
                        <xsd:element name="CA_TAG" type="CA_TAG_schemeType" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:simpleType name="CA_TAG_schemeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>';
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.STA11
(   
    ID_STA11 int NOT NULL,    
    COD_ARTICU varchar(15) NOT NULL,        
    CAMPOS_ADICIONALES xml(CONTENT dbo.CAMPOS_ADICIONALES_STA11) NULL
    
 CONSTRAINT PK_STA11 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ID_STA11 ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];
GO

INSERT dbo.STA11 (ID_STA11, COD_ARTICU, CAMPOS_ADICIONALES) VALUES
(0, '0100100129',  
    N'<CAMPOS_ADICIONALES>
    <CA_TAG></CA_TAG>
</CAMPOS_ADICIONALES>');

-- before
SELECT * FROM dbo.STA11
WHERE COD_ARTICU = '0100100129';

UPDATE dbo.STA11
SET CAMPOS_ADICIONALES.modify('
  replace value of (/CAMPOS_ADICIONALES/CA_TAG)[1]
  with "Hello" cast as CA_TAG_schemeType?
')
WHERE COD_ARTICU = '0100100129';

-- after
SELECT * FROM dbo.STA11
WHERE COD_ARTICU = '0100100129';
```

**SQL #2**

If you need to update by using a T-SQL variable.

```
DECLARE @ValorCampoAdicional VARCHAR(100) = 'Hello there';

UPDATE dbo.STA11
SET CAMPOS_ADICIONALES.modify('
  replace value of (/CAMPOS_ADICIONALES/CA_TAG)[1]
  with sql:variable("@ValorCampoAdicional") cast as CA_TAG_schemeType?
')
WHERE COD_ARTICU = '0100100129';
```

Comment: I was waiting for your answer! :)

Comment: Judging by your answer, it seems I was right and `/text()` is superfluous

Comment: `.../text()` is needed for *untyped* XML only. Without `text()`, SQL Server will emit an  error.

Comment: Thank you  @YitzhakKhabinsky This aproach has solved my problem with the update of the xml field, but...now I need one mor thing, you know if it is posible to  use an SQL variable for the xml node name?

Comment: The question is not clear. Please post a brand new question.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky  I have updated the Question with the new situation, would you look at it and tell me what do you think? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: It is impossible to do. The XPath expression shall be **literal**